# Whenever I transform into a vampire lord and back I turn invisible and have multiple sets of gear equipped

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Whenever I transform into a vampire lord and back my character turns invisible except for gear and she has multiple pieces of gear in each spot. If the specifics matter I was wearing nightingale boots everything except armor (chest piece?) which was the thieves guild armor for the carry limit buff before the transformation. After I turn back back into a dark elf I notice I'm wearing the same gear as before but also wearing an elven helmet and the rest of my thieves guild gear as well but my character herself doesn't show up (it looks like floating armor). Why does this happen and is there any way I can either stop it from happening or at least stop it from making my character invisible?

Mods loaded when it happened in case it's useful info:

- Glowing Books (I don't remember the exact name but it makes unread books glow)
- UNP (I think that's the name, it's a nude mod)
- Some mod that added more realistic/immersive NPC behavior which I also can't remember the name of

Comment: Could you perhaps paste your full modlist here? Because this really sounds like a mod interfering.

Comment: Those are the only 3 mods I had installed

Comment: If you can't remember the names of the mods, how are you loading them? Did you just drop them in your Skyrim/Data folder?

Comment: @Joachim Vortex. The thing Nexus mods gives you to use

Comment: So, what titles does Vortex mention?